# Passing an OAuth token to the Yahoo API

Tags: php, api, yahoo

I have created a new app using the Yahoo API. How can I pass the required headers using CURL functionality? I got this error message when I tried:

```
<yahoo:error xml:lang="en-US"><yahoo:description>Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="unable_to_determine_oauth_type", realm="yahooapis.com"</yahoo:description></yahoo:error>
```

How can I pass the required headers in this code:

```
$url ="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/team/223.l.431.t.1";  
$ch = curl_init(); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);   
//get the url contents  
$data = curl_exec($ch);     
//execute curl request curl_close($ch);   
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);    
print_r($xml);    
exit;
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: How we can pass headers here.                                                           $url ="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/team/223.l.431.t.1";
 

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents

$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

print_r($xml);exit;

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27903093/edit) and add the code in the comment to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you'd obtained an OAuth 2.0 access token, use it in the following code:

```
$token = "<token>";

$url = "https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/team/223.l.431.t.1?format=json";

$headers = array(
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($response);
print_r($json);
```

Notice that it presents the token in an `Authorization` HTTP header over a secure transport channel using the `https` URL scheme and requests to return the content as JSON using the `format` URL query parameter.

Comment: Can anyone tell how to create token from consumer key and secret